# What happens if I manually delete one of the VMs that Dataflow created?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I see the GCE instances that Dataflow created for my job in the GCE console. What happens if I delete them?

Answer (score 2):

Manually altering resources provisioned by Google Cloud Dataflow is an unsupported operation. It will interfere with Dataflow’s clean-up process and might result in leftover resources and therefore extra cost. In particular, deleting the VMs of a streaming Dataflow job might leave persistent disks around, which will still be billed.

Using the Dataflow provisioned VMs or Persistent Disks for other purposes than the Dataflow job is also not supported. Do not attempt to reattach the disks to other machines, or to get the VMs to run other independent programs. The Dataflow service might get rid of these resources at any point, without warning, and any data on these resources will be lost.