# Google Cloud Dataflow: can not kill a Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Google Cloud Dataflow job that seems stuck since over 2 days now (normally takes about 7-10 mins).

In the web UI "cancel job" did nothing, by now the button has even disappeared.

I did kill the VMs used by the job, but they respawn.

`gcloud dataflow jobs drain 2018-08-09_18_44_22-352631881911297226` and/or `gcloud dataflow jobs cancel 2018-08-09_18_44_22-352631881911297226` do not work, there only is the error

> Could not cancel workflow; user does not have sufficient permissions
>   on project: svb-bi-bq, or the job doesnot exist in the project

However, the user has a role of Dataflow Administrator, so the access rights should be ok.

What else can I do to kill this job?

Comment: I landed here for a different reason... for future people like me: Also note you _cannot_ substitute the NAME for the JOB_ID. Use the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping/deleting the dataflow VMs is strongly advised against. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#resource-usage-and-management) page in docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426026/what-happens-if-i-manually-delete-one-of-the-vms-that-dataflow-created) answer to an older question for more details. What you should do at this point is either try and contact support (you can do so via your console) or create an issue in the [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=1100337) to ask for your job to get force-cancelled.

Comment: Thank you for getting back on this. For anybody else ever having this problem, raising an issue with support is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Also be careful with the `[--region=REGION_ID]` param.

I just discovered that this command doesn't work:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs drain 2018-11-13_04_01_20-7650245364499275562
```

But this does:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs drain 2018-11-13_04_01_20-7650245364499275562 --region europe-west1
```

My gcloud configuration has the right region set... But for some reason the drain command just ignore it.